# How to use a model field for multiple models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model **BstUserActionLog** with a foreign key to Django model **User**. I have another model for user profile information, **BstUserProfile**. When I do serialize **BstUserActionLog** with ModelSerializer I do have Django **User** info serialized as it is supposed to be. But I also need to add **BstUserProfile** serialized using the same user_id used for **User** model.

How can I serialize **BstUserActionLog** with model **User** and **BstUserProfile** are both serialized?

**From my models.py:**

```
class BstUserActionLog(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bst_action_type = models.ForeignKey(BstActionType)
    action_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bst_book = models.ForeignKey(BstBook)
    new_value_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    old_value_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bst_user_action_log'

class BstUserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_avatar_uploaded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cover_uploaded = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bst_user_profile'
        app_label = 'bst'
```

**From my serializers.py:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username',)

class BstUserActionLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = BstUserActionLog
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'bst_action_type', 'action_date', 'bst_book', 'new_value_id', 'old_value_id')
        depth = 3
```

Comment: I guess [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to my solution is [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). With this a new field can be added which is calculated with a method. This method signature contains the object to be serialized. After that a regular method serializer is used to return the serialized object.

**From my serializers.py**

```
class BstUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BstUserProfile
        fields = ('is_avatar_uploaded', 'is_cover_uploaded')

class BstUserActionLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    user_profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_user_profile(self, obj):
        try:
            user_profile = BstUserProfile.objects.get(user_id=obj.user_id)
            return BstUserProfileSerializer(user_profile).data
        except Exception as e:
            return {}

    class Meta:
        model = BstUserActionLog
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'user_profile', 'bst_action_type', 'action_date', 'bst_book', 'new_value_id', 'old_value_id')
        depth = 3
```

Comment: You could even make `user` use a `SerializerMethodField` and combine the user and user profile data together. Or, make `UserSerializer` fetch the user profile and combine it with its output.

Comment: @foresmac Yes, different combinations can be also used. `SerializerMethodField` is very handy.